# Linux device driver can't find headers

Tags: c, linux, makefile

I am working on a device driver. I want to include some standard libraries with this driver. However, on running the MakeFile it returns with the error stating:

"fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
7 | #include <stdio.h>"

I used other programs with the same includes, if I compile those on linux with gcc it works perfectly fine. However, with the MakeFile it just can't find it.

This is my MakeFile:

```
TARGET_MODULE:=Kurniawan-Meulenbeld-module

# If we running by kernel building system
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
        $(TARGET_MODULE)-objs := main.o device_file.o SevenSegment.o
        obj-m := $(TARGET_MODULE).o

# If we are running without kernel build system
else
        BUILDSYSTEM_DIR:=/lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build
        PWD:=$(shell pwd)


all :
# run kernel build system to make module
        $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDSYSTEM_DIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
# run kernel build system to cleanup in current directory
        $(MAKE) -C $(BUILDSYSTEM_DIR) M=$(PWD) clean

load:
        insmod ./$(TARGET_MODULE).ko

unload:
        rmmod ./$(TARGET_MODULE).ko

endif
```

Any way I can include these libraries into my device driver?

Comment: You can't use most user space libraries in the kernel.

Comment: You can't use *any* userspace libraries in the kernel.  That includes most of the C standard library, too, though you may use several of the standard library headers that declare only types and macros, not functions or objects.  The kernel does have some of its own I/O functions, however, such as `printk`, and its own versions of a few standard library functions.  You'll want to use kernel headers, not C standard library headers, to get declarations of those.  The C-language concept to look up is "freestanding implementation".

Comment: @JohnBollinger, Thank you for the information, do you by any chance have a sugestion on how I would be able to run a script or program from my device driver? It will contain the libraries I need. I already tried the system command, but stdlib is also not allowed in the kernel userspace.

Comment: The kernel, including drivers within, does not run its own processes.  Possibly you want to write a userspace utility associated with your driver, but it would need to be started at the initiative of something running in userspace, not by the kernel.  This approach is very common -- as just one example, consider the `mount` command.  If that doesn't adequately meet your needs then you probably need to revise your design.